# Encrypting to standard output with gnupg

Tags: shell, stdout, gnupg

I'm trying to encrypt something with `gpg -a` and return the result to standard out rather than a file. According to the [manual](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r636.html), it should be sufficient to omit an `--output` flag, but that doesn't seem to be the case. When I don't specify an output file, gnupg assumes I'm outputting to `[input-file].gpg` rather than stdout.

Is there a way to have GPG do this, or am I going to have to have it encrypt to a temporary file and then `cat` it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of passing the input file to gpg, use shell redirection to send the input file to gpg's stdin, e.g.:

```
gpg -ac < inputfile
```

Answer (score 26):

Just in case anyone still needs to do this, you can do it with

```
gpg -ac -o- infile
```

Setting the output filename to "-" sends the output to stdout.

Answer (score 4):

If anybody else needs a better or more concise answer:

You can do `gpg --output -` with any other flags.

For the example above you can do `gpg --armor --symmetric --output - file.txt` or `gpg -aco - file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

edit: sorry realised you wanted symmetric encryption

`gpg -a -c`
prompt will come up for the password, after that type your message
then press ctrl+d

`gpg -a --encrypt -r recipient@gmail.com`

then type message, when you're done press ctrl+d